# Пример на Multiplexing Server

Tags: клиент-сервер, java, gameserver, сокет

Нужен пример кода для сервер-клиента на Multiplexing Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что понимать под multiplexing server. Если это понимается как сервер слушающий несколько сокетов (мультиплексирующий между сокетами) - то пример как сервера, так и клиента подробно разобран в Java in a Nutshell (3rd edition). Поройтесь в торрентах за "Java Examples in a Nutshell 3rd edition". Начало примера в открытом доступе [здесь](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/0596006209/new-i-o/jenut3-chp-6-sect-9)

Comment: multiplexing server это все же обычно сервер, слушающий один порт и обслуживающий несколько клиентов всего одним процессом. Хотя судя по ссылке мы говорим об одном и том же.

Comment: Возможно. Просто под multiplexing понимается довольно много всего

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю еще один подробно разжеванный пример, т.к. Safari не всем доступен: [Use select for high-speed networking](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0411-select.html?page=1)

[Сами исходники](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/select/jw-0411-select.zip)